# How is the Logos person after incarnation?

Tags: persons-of-the-trinity, incarnation, logos

I already searched in case my question has been questioned. But I cannot find it.

From this [link](https://www.gotquestions.org/God-incarnate.html) I read :

> Question:
>  What does incarnate mean? How was Jesus God incarnate?
>
> Answer:
>  The Latin verb incarnare meant “to make flesh.” When we say
> that Jesus Christ is God “Incarnate,” we mean that the Son of God took
> on a fleshly, bodily form (John 1:14).
>
> However, when this happened in
> the womb of Mary, Jesus’ earthly mother, He did not stop being deity.
> Although Jesus became fully human (Hebrews 2:17), He retained His
> status as God (John 1:1, 14).
>
> **How Jesus is able to be both man and God**
> **simultaneously is one of the great mysteries of Christianity**

To me, I don't find that *"The Logos is able to be both man and God simultaneously"* is a mystery at all. Here is why :

1. The Logos is God, eternal, infinite.
2. The Logos took on a fleshly, bodily form
3. However, when this happened in the womb of Mary, The incarnated-Logos earthly mother, The Logos did not stop being God.
4. So there are two existencies of one Person (The Logos), The Logos who still as fully God (without a form) and The incarnated-Logos as a fully human being inside the womb of Mary.

To me, it's not a mystery because the Logos as God (without a form) is omnipotent. So, even if (for example) I add another Logos existency in a form of Theophany who appear somewhere in Timbuktu while at the same time the same Person as a human being (incarnated) inside the womb of Mary ... to me it's not impossible.

Because the article said that *"How The Logos is able to be both man and God simultaneously is one of the great mysteries of Christianity"*, then it seems my four-points-opinion above is not correct.

So my question is:
*In what way is the "great mystery" of it in the point of view of Christianity ?*

PS:
 whenever I read "Jesus" name in the article above, my mind "shift" to the eternal Logos, not to the incarnated-Logos inside Mary's womb.

Comment: "Logos Person" is wholly redundant (like 'the Father Person'). You should just edit out all instances of "person."

Comment: @SolaGratia, Thank you for the correction. I've deleted some "person" word (not all) because I still need to point out that what I mean here is the person. Please tell me if it's OK now.

Comment: Please consider reading my answer to this question in connection to your question in relations to the Logos https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/38260/is-john-11-3-an-allusion-to-proverbs-822-31-lxx/38262#38262

Comment: Which denomination is claiming that this is a mystery?  To many, it isn't even a fact, much less a mystery.  E.g. Philippians 2:7 says "he gave up his divine privileges; he took the humble position of a slave and was born as a human being" (NLT).  I.e. it's hardly an established fact that Jesus wasn't fully human.  Some believe that surrendering his divinity and then living and dying as a human was essential for our salvation -- he actually risked his life and would have permanently died had he ever sinned.  It's not much of a sacrifice if you know you'll come back to life.

Comment: Many people struggle with the idea that the creator of the universe humbled himself and took on human flesh, a creator so superior could not, they would say, dwell in such a simple creature as a man. The idea is now and was then, unbelievable to some.  The greater test of belief oddly, is a much more controversial dogma,, that that same incarnate God gives himself to us in an even more Mundane form, that of simple bread and wine.   The idea was then, and is now a huge test of Faith for a Christian.

Comment: @Ray I'm pleased to see you say this, 'he actually risked his life and would have permanently died had he ever sinned'. Perfect! But how could this be if, as you say, he is still God? He is either God or he is fully human. How can he be made like us in every way and *die* - and still be fully God?

Comment: @user47952, giving up immortality is part of what giving up "his divine privileges" means. ¶ As an analogy, consider an ambassador and his family living in another country. They all have diplomatic immunity, in theory giving them freedom to break any law they like, with at worst being asked to leave the country as a result. Now suppose the diplomat's son decides to give up his immunity and live like a typical person of that country.  If he breaks their law, he can now be imprisoned or suffer capital punishment, and there is nothing he or his father can do about it.

Comment: @Ray, nice story but, nah sorry, simply, God cannot *stop being God*. The very concept is without merit. Phil 2 states he is the form of God - not that he abandoned this. Being the form or image is clearly not being God. we are made in the image of God (through Christ) - we are not God either but will be *like* God. Jesus was *like God*, being holy and w/o sin - that's what the 'form' means. Jesus cannot be God and die - let alone be tempted or sin. OR, it's all a masquerade.

Comment: @karma You wrote, in your PS: "whenever I read 'Jesus' name in the article above, my mind 'shift' to the eternal Logos, not to the incarnated-Logos inside Mary's womb." Haven't you forgotten something? How about [Jesus Sitting At The Right Hand Of The Father](https://www.openbible.info/topics/jesus_sitting_at_the_right_hand_of_the_father)?

Comment: I believe @karma has formulated the question taking for granted that the Logos (Greek *logos*) is a person or, to use the fancier expression coined by Easten theologians, a *hypostasis*. In [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/83107/17257) to another question, I have explained that the *logos* is not a "he", not a person, before the incarnation.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really make out what you're asking here.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're wrestling with is how the definition of "person" is applied to deity.  What does it mean that God is a "person"?  Once this is nailed down, Trinity emerges as the only consistent solution, if one takes the New Testament as accurate.  Thus, Logos is Christ, begotten from eternity, and yet also begotten in the flesh 2000 years ago.  And he is a separate person from God the father.  And so on.

This is distinct from things like pantheism or panentheism, one of which is that God can be everywhere at the same time, or modalism, where God shows up in different forms (modes) based on how He wants to do something.  In the former, for example, God no longer needs to be a jealous God.  Jealous of what?  Every divine appearance is Him.  That's not the God of the Bible. In the latter, God by definition can't have a genuine conversation with himself.  That's not the God of the New Testament.

Comment: You wrote : _"Logos is Christ, begotten from eternity"_. So, in my mind like this : Before the Incarnation (and eternally), Christ is fully God (one person with one nature) , after the Incarnation, now Christ is fully God and fully man (one person with two natures). I cannot find where is the "doesn't make sense" of that which cause a mystery. On the other hand (continued)

Comment: On the other hand from your writing _"God by definition can't have a genuine conversation with himself"_, to me is odd. One can play chess against himself as if there are two persons (two players). So, Why can't God have a genuine conversation with himself when there is He as God and the same He as man ? Can't He limit himself before He became a man ? If He can't then to me this is a mystery :).

Comment: Yeah, I think you're going to have to do a dive into theology proper.  I'm not a good resource for this!

Comment: There are lots of things to think about here.  For example, when God becomes man, what does that mean if it doesn't include losing his ability to be everywhere except one place?

Comment: _"when God becomes man, what does that mean if it doesn't include losing his ability to be everywhere except one place?"_. I wonder about that also :). And if it doesn't include losing his ability to be everywhere except one place, then I think it's not God becomes man, but God becomes Theophany :).

Comment: @rje You write: " Jealous of what? Every divine appearance is Him." Are you saying that God (at least the way He is presented in the OT) is jealous (viz. of Israel going after alien "gods")? Are you saying (or implying) that, if pantheism was right, God would be present even in those alien "gods", and therefore there would no reason for Him to be jealous? Or what? Please clarify :)